# An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: db2

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EFMREFNO 
   BEFORE 
   INSERT ON FEEDBACK_CASE_TB 
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN 
   SELECT SEQ_EFMREFNO.NEXTVAL INTO:NEW.EFMREFNO FROM DUAL;
   END;
```

please help me it's give errors

> An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EFMREFNO
>          BEFOR" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "`<revoke>`".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.12.79
>
> An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN `<joined_table>`".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.12.79

Please give the solution for that errors

Comment: no i am directly using trigeer. actual i m going to create database for my project. can you provide me any solution for this pls help. my all work dependent on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 things going on here -

1) When the ";" character is part of the SQL statement, it's necessary to use a different character to terminate the statement.   I typically use "@".   To tell the "db2" command that you have chosen a different character, use

```
db2 -td@
```

or if you want to read from a file

```
db2 -td@ -f <somefile>
```

2) The correct way to update new row in a trigger is to set an alias for the new row, and use a set clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EFMREFNO 
   BEFORE 
   INSERT ON FEEDBACK_CASE_TB 
   REFERENCING NEW AS N
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN 
       SET N.EFMREFNO = SEQ_EFMREFNO.NEXTVAL;
   END
@
```

There may be other ways to use the sequence with the default clause in the create table statement that will accomplish the same thing:

Comment: hey it's not workin it's also not allowed A at the end of END ??

Comment: pls resolve my problem this solution is not wrkng..... can you suggest any solution for that Q ????

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.   I did actually create the table and sequence, and test the statement.   How are you running the create trigger statement - with the "db2" command or one of the GUI tools like "control center".  Unfortunately I can't give a lesson on UML here, but I can try to answer DB2-specific questions, and general SQL questions. I can't see what's in your diagram, or know what tables you have in your database. Keep in mind, I don't work for IBM, but am a private DB2 consultant reading his e-mail at Starbucks at 6:00 am on a Sunday.

Comment: I had a thought about control center - You can set the line termination character in a bottom of the window.  In this photo, see the ";" at the bottom of the window -- change it to a "@".  That is the equivalent of the "db2 -td@" syntax for the command-line version. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0603saracco2/CommandEditor.gif