# Creating stored procedure in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure in db2 as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MIS.TEST_PROC1 (IN ID INT) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
-- Declare cursor
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT REM
    FROM MIS.BOOKING;
     -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;
    END P1;
```

But it throws error as shown below,

```
ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.66.46
```

In Data Studio, it start showing error from the line "P1: BEGIN" itself.
This Procedure has to be created in IBM Data Studio 4.1
Can anyone please check if I have missed anything in this

Comment: It would probably help to know platform/version, but I'm 90% certain you don't need `P1` in there at all (or the colon, either).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger/13271559

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error in data studio at line 
`P1: BEGIN` is that you are probably trying to create the SP from SQL Editor 
instead of creating it from Routine Editor.

Here is what you should do:

1. From Data Source Explorer, Connect to your database.
2. From Data Project Explorer, create a new data development project with the connection that you connected from DSE.
3. Now under your project, right click on stored procedure and then click new
   use any template or just take default and then you will see a new Routine editor opened.

I tested this simple code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db2inst1.TEST_PROC1 (IN ID INT) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
-- Declare cursor
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT NAME
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES;
     -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;
END P1
```

Note: You don't need `;` at the end of P1.

Now deploy this to SP to db2 by clicking on the Deploy icon next to Save button on top right corner of the Routine Editor.