# Error declaring variable & if-statement

Tags: db2

I am trying to write a stored procedure that uses if statements and variables however I keep getting a SQL0104N error. It seems to have difficulty with the declaring of the variables. I have also tried substituting the 'v' prefix with a '@' to denote local variable but it doesn't seem to help. error says unxpected token 'DECLARE vCUBE DOUBLE'

Any insight would be very helpful. Code is listed below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DIMENSION_CALC(
  IN iORID INTEGER,
  IN iPIECES DOUBLE,
  IN iLENGTH_1 DOUBLE,
  IN iLENGTH_UNITS DOUBLE,
  IN iWIDTH DOUBLE,
  IN iWIDTH_UNITS DOUBLE,
  IN iHEIGHT DOUBLE,
  IN iHEIGHT_UNITS DOUBLE,
  IN iCUBE DOUBLE,
  IN iCUBE_UNITS DOUBLE
  )
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE vCUBE DOUBLE;
  DECLARE vLINEAR DOUBLE;
  SET vCUBE = iPIECES * GET_CUBE(iCUBE, iCUBE_UNITS, iHEIGHT, iHEIGHT_UNITS, iWIDTH, iWIDTH_UNITS, iLENGTH_1, iLENGTH_UNITS);
  IF CALC_LENGTH(iWIDTH_UNITS, iWIDTH) * iPIECES <= 4 THEN
    SET vLINEAR = MULTIPLIER_LINEAR_FEET(4) * CALC_LENGTH(iLENGTH_UNITS,iLENGTH);
  ELSEIF CALC_LENGTH(iWIDTH_UNITS, iWIDTH)*iPIECES > 4 AND CALC_LENGTH(iWIDTH_UNITS, iWIDTH)<= 4 THEN
    SET vLINEAR = MULTIPLIER_LINEAR_FEET(CALC_LENGTH(iWIDTH_UNITS, iWIDTH)*iPIECES) * CALC_LENGTH(iLENGTH_UNITS,iLENGTH_1);
  ELSEIF CALC_LENGTH(iWIDTH_UNITS, iWIDTH) > 4 THEN
    SET vLINEAR = iPIECES * CALC_LENGTH(iLENGTH_UNITS,iLENGTH_1);
  END IF;
  IF TOTAL_LINEAR(iORID) >= 10 THEN
    UPDATE TLDTL SET
      CUBE = vLINEAR * 100,
      WHERE ORDER_ID = iORID;
  ELSEIF TOTAL_LINEAR(iORID) < 10 THEN
    UPDATE TLDTL SET
      CUBE = vCUBE
      WHERE ORDER_ID = iORID;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: never saw something like this `LANGUAGE SQL`

Comment: Your code looks nothing like SQL Server.  Please tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: What is your (outer) statement delimiter?

Comment: Tagged {db2}, but what is the version and what is the platform?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger/13271559#13271559