# DB2 trigger on update

Tags: db2, db2-luw, database-trigger

I have the table `ORDERS` with a lot of columns: `(ORDERS_ID, MEMBER_ID, STATUS, ANY MORE....)`
when in `STATUS` I will have the change in the new status 'M' I would save `ORDERS_ID, MEMBER_ID, STATUS` in another table `XORDERSAUDIT`.
I wrote this :

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER Order_Status_Update_Trigger
     AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON ORDERS
     REFERENCING NEW AS N
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (N.STATUS = 'M')
     BEGIN ATOMIC
       INSERT INTO XORDERSAUDIT
         (ORDER_ID, USERS_ID, STATUS) VALUES (N.ORDERS_ID, N.MEMBER_ID, N.STATUS);
     END;
```

and I have this error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;MEMBER_ID, N.STATUS);,
>   DRIVER=4.19.66 SQLState:  42601 ErrorCode: -104 Error occurred in:

I don't understand the error, I try to correct but encountered the same error, please help me.

Comment: What is the statement terminator? It could be if you are using the default ";" then the parser thinks it is done after the INSERT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)