# Syntax error when creating a stored procedure in IBM DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I can't execute the procedure, the error states:

> An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "ent.payment_id)*0.50". Expected tokens may include: "". LINE NUMBER=6. SQLSTATE=42601.

This procedure is to update the total price when the code is valid. I try two ways of doing it. Can anyone help?

```
create procedure Prc_Discount(in code char(3), payment_id integer)
begin
 if (code ='abc')then
update payment
set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.50;
else
 if (code ='bac')then
update payment
set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.75;
else
 if (code ='cba')then
update payment
set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.90;
end if;
end@
```

Another attempt:

```
create procedure Prc_Discount(in code char(3), payment_id integer)
begin
case code
   when abc then                      
      update payment
      set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
      where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.50;         
   when acd then                                                     
      update payment
      set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
      where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.75; 
   else      
      update payment
      set new.total_price =(select total_price from payment
      where new.payment_id=payment.payment_id)*0.90;         
end case; 
end@
```

Comment: How is this Java related?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry not related at all.

Comment: Then please remove the confusing Java question tag. I can't do this as there is an edit pending on your question.

Comment: Why cannot you execute the procedure? Do you not know how? Is your database up and running? Can you connect to it?

Comment: @mustaccio I cant execute the procedure, it states  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
"ent.payment_id)*0.50".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".  
LINE NUMBER=6.  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Then may be you could update your question with this information to make it a bit more answerable?

Comment: @mustaccio ok, Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Did you specify "@" as the statement terminator in whatever tool you use to run your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements? See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger/13271559#13271559

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for your help, I've finally can execute the procedure. :)

Comment: you can simplify your code like in my example if you want

Answer (score 0):

try this into your procedure

```
update payment f1
set f1.total_price =
        case 
        when code ='abc' then 0.50 * f1.total_price
        when code ='bac' then 0.75 * f1.total_price
        when code ='cba' then 0.90 * f1.total_price
        else f1.total_price
        end
where code in ('abc', 'bac', 'cba')
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting this above in your code :

"--  "

replace "end@" by "end;"

Comment: -- <ScriptOptions statementTerminator=";" />