# UDF on DB2 11.0

Tags: sql, db2, udf, db2-zos

I was asked to build a user defined function on our Mainframe environment that checks for a search string in a longer string. The only catch is that if we search for example for 'AA' in 'ABCAADAA' the only valid result is the last AA because the first AA actually split in CA and AD.

```
CREATE FUNCTION F#CRE#WK (WK CHAR(02), WKATTR CHAR(10))
    RETURNS INTEGER 
    LANGUAGE SQL
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE INDEX INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE (INDEX < 9) DO
        SET INDEX = LOCATE_IN_STRING(WKATTR, WK, INDEX);
        IF (MOD(INDEX, 2) <> 0) THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN 0;
END;
```

It is working fine when I implement it using Data Studio but if I put it onto the host directly (we're using Quick32770) I'm getting a bunch of errors which don't make sense at all. I couldn't find any helpful resources(searched the whole IBM page and Google of course).

First error I'm getting is:

```
SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME  
SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: ;
```

Which refers to the line I'm declaring my index variable. If I remove the semicolon it tells me that the SET is illegal there because it is expecting a semicolon. 
I cannot think of anything else I could try(I messed around with the code a lot but errors just kept getting more weird.). I started working in this field while being in college just a couple of weeks ago and nobody here has actual knowledge about this so I was hoping to find some help here. 
If there's anything else you need, just let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/754686-db2-udf-need-eliminate-if-statement

It says the if statement is not allowed on the mainframe in UDF ?
So this user bend it around to a CASE function.

Comment: Thanks for that! I won't be able to test it until Monday but I'll make sure to report back. What I'm guessing (and my team also) is that it's a problem with the mainframe setup but we can't change it because we don't know what we need to change.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this you need to go into the SPUFI settings and change the TERMINATOR option to something else than a semicolon. If I changed it to & my code must look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F#CRE#WK (WK CHAR(02), WKATTR CHAR(10))
RETURNS INTEGER 
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE INDEX INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE (INDEX < 9) DO
        SET INDEX = LOCATE_IN_STRING(WKATTR, WK, INDEX);
        IF (MOD(INDEX, 2) <> 0) THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN 0;
END&
```