# DB2 Trigger before insert

Tags: db2, database-trigger

DB2 Trigger before insert not working to delete a row in table

```
CREATE TRIGGER WDW.user_name_search_del
before INSERT ON WDW.user_name_search_b
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
Delete from wdw.user_name_search_b
where user_name = new.user_name ;--
```

it is throwing the error

> An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "name = new.user_name".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to fix:

1. Change "BEGIN ATOMIC" to just "BEGIN". DELETE is not supported in a "BEGIN ATOMIC" block
2. Add "; END" before ";--" to end the "BEGIN" block.

Statement should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WDW.user_name_search_del 
  before INSERT ON WDW.user_name_search_b 
  REFERENCING NEW AS new 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  MODE DB2SQL 
BEGIN  
  Delete 
  from wdw.user_name_search_b 
  where user_name = new.user_name; 
END;
```

Comment: thank  you but when  i  tried it is throwing the below error An unexpected token "BEGIN  
  Delete" was found following "ROW 
  MODE DB2SQL 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601

Comment: Change the statement separator at the end of the statement from ‘;’ to, let’s say, ‘@‘, and specify the same statement separator in your tool you use to run this statement.