# Create History Trigger Db2

Tags: db2

I am trying to create a trigger that copys a newly INSERTED and/or UPDATED record from one table to a History version of this table. The purpose is to keep a record every time a record in a table is inserted and/or updated.

This is the Create Trigger statement syntax that I have, following the IBM Db2 Trigger site.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "TADB2"."HIST_CSEMASTER_Z_LOG"
AFTER UPDATE ON TADB2.CSEMASTER_Z
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO TADB2.HIST_CSEMASTER_Z
values (N.CSEMASTERID, N.CURRID, N.SUBCURRID, N.EXPIREDATE, N.CREATEDATE, N.CUSTVIEWNUM, N.CSEMSTRNAME, N.JOINCODE, N.CONTACTCOUNTRYCD, N.CONTACTSERIALNUM, N.AUDIENCECD, N.SPONSORNAME, N.AVAILABLEDATE, N.OWNERCOUNTRYCD, N.OWNERSERIALNUM, N.PRMWWCHAPTERID, N.PRMWWSUBCHAPTERID, N.SECWWCHAPTERID, N.SECWWSUBCHAPTERID, N.INTRANETIND, N.TINSERTTS, N.TLASTUPDTS, N.IBM_TRADEMARK, N.OTHER_TRADEMARK, N.INTERNETIND, N.BRANDID, N.BUSINESSID, N.LIFECYCLE_STATUS);
END;
```

The error I am receiving is:

[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "N.LIFECYCLE_STATUS)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.44

I've tried:

- Removing the END
- Removing the semi-colon after the END
- Removing the semi-colon after the N.LIFECYCLE_STATUS);

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Db2 Temporal Tables for that. If you just use [System Temporal](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0058477.html) functionality it would provide already the functionality you describe.

Worth to check it out

Answer (score 0):

You must use different from ';' statement terminator in your tool.
Below is an example for DB2 Command Line Processor, which understands the first line as a directive to do this.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TRIGGER "TADB2"."HIST_CSEMASTER_Z_LOG"
AFTER UPDATE ON TADB2.CSEMASTER_Z
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
  INSERT INTO TADB2.HIST_CSEMASTER_Z
  values (N.CSEMASTERID, N.CURRID, N.SUBCURRID, N.EXPIREDATE, N.CREATEDATE, N.CUSTVIEWNUM, N.CSEMSTRNAME, N.JOINCODE, N.CONTACTCOUNTRYCD, N.CONTACTSERIALNUM, N.AUDIENCECD, N.SPONSORNAME, N.AVAILABLEDATE, N.OWNERCOUNTRYCD, N.OWNERSERIALNUM, N.PRMWWCHAPTERID, N.PRMWWSUBCHAPTERID, N.SECWWCHAPTERID, N.SECWWSUBCHAPTERID, N.INTRANETIND, N.TINSERTTS, N.TLASTUPDTS, N.IBM_TRADEMARK, N.OTHER_TRADEMARK, N.INTERNETIND, N.BRANDID, N.BUSINESSID, N.LIFECYCLE_STATUS);
END@
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Barinstein. I tried your solution above and unfortunately I still am receiving the same error. Additionally I am now receiving this error below:


[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END@".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29

Comment: What environment or editor are you using to submit this statement?

Comment: Once again: you must change a statement terminator used in your tool. Your jbdc based tool doesn't understand the directive I mentioned. You must find a place in your tool where you can do it.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Ahh I see what you mean. I am wondering where I can place this in my tool. Maybe you all have insight? The tool I am using is DB Visualizer 10.0.15 on macOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Follow the [Executing Complex Statements](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG91/Executing+Complex+Statements) link.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein even with the new syntax, I am receiving this error. [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "++" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.44

Comment: Use some another tool which understands its own statement terminator set in its session then. To be honest I don't know what's wrong with it...

Comment: Use IBM Data Studio (or IBM Data Server Manager) if writing triggers and stored procs. It syntax parses locally, and saves a lot of pain if you ensure you have no red underlines before you hit Run SQL !