# How to fix DB2 Error "An unexpected token CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT"

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I am trying to create a db2 trigger so that a transaction history is maintained in a separate table. But I am getting below error and unable to proceed.

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER HISTORY_TRIGGER
>   AFTER" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may
>   include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=
>   4.22.29

I am executing the sql through dbeaver.

I have already tried [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger) and it doesn't help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER HISTORY_TRIGGER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON MY_SCHEMA.TRANSACTIONS_TABLE
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS OLD
            NEW ROW AS NEW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.HISTORY_TABLE
    (ID, EMAIL, REASON, ROLE, TIMESTAMP)
    VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.EMAIL, NEW.REASON, NEW.ROLE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END
```

Please help me to find out what is wrong with my sql trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)

Comment: @mustaccio as I have mentioned in the question itself i have already tried that. But seems like I had to change the default delimiter in dbeaver like Mark has mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window->Preferences->General->Editors->SQL Editor->SQL Processing->Statement delimiter: @

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HISTORY_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON MY_SCHEMA.TRANSACTIONS_TABLE
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.HISTORY_TABLE (ID, EMAIL, REASON, ROLE, TIMESTAMP)
    VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.EMAIL, NEW.REASON, NEW.ROLE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END@
```

Comment: Before someone says to insert the old values into history.  I want to say Its much easier to query history knowing the last value is the most recent in the table that is being tracked.