# db2 - CASE WHEN or IF Statement in CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: function, if-statement, db2, case

Hi I've got a problem managing CASE WHEN or IF Statements in a CREATE FUNCTION Call in DB2
I tried this Statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NAECHSTES_DATUM(PARAM1 CHAR(6), PARAM2 DATE)
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE BASEDATE DATE;
    DECLARE THATDATE DATE;
    SET BASEDATE = TO_DATE(CONCAT(PARAM1,CAST(YEAR(PARAM2) AS CHAR(4))),'DD.MM.YYYY');
    IF (BASEDATE >= PARAM2) 
    THEN SET THATDATE = BASEDATE;
    ELSE SET THATDATE = BASEDATE + 1 YEAR;
    END IF;
    RETURN THATDATE;
END
```

I get this error

[-104] Auf "+ 1 YEAR" folgte das unerwartete Token "END-OF-STATEMENT".  Mögliche Tokens: "
    END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.14.113

Similar result when I use CASE WHEN.

Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unexpected token "CREATE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alternative statement delimiter after the END of the function.

Inside the function the statement delimiter is the semicolon (;)

But Db2 needs to know an additional delimiter to indicate the end of the block.

For the Db2 command line (in shell scripts, batch files) you can use the "-td@" command line option and terminate the block with the @ character. Inside a file that contains the function you can use:

`--#SET TERMINATOR @`
anywhere before the function block and then terminate the block with @

If you are use a GUI tool to submit the DDL or SQL, each GUI tool has its own way to specify alternative statement delimiters. Look at the settings and properties.  It's always wise to fully describe your toolset (which programs, which versions, which operating system etc) in your question.

Comment: Thank you! The hint about the delimiter made it clear to me. I got it working running it within a sql scipt in dbeaver and also in liquibase. When I set "Ignore native delimiter" it worked with dbeaver. In Liquibase you need to use the <createProcedure> tag. Otherwise it won't work.